# How do I import one flat file into two tables with a join

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm new to SSIS and I'm looking to import a flat text file containing people data and two kinds of address data, residential and mailing. My database schema consists of two tables, the Person table and the Address table with a join table because I have a many-to-many relationship between the people and addresses.

What I've accomplished successfully in SSIS so far is importing the people records and then processing the file to process the two kinds of addresses, but you can see the problem. There's no linking data between the two for me to make the join table, so I'm certain I can't do this in serial (import all people data, then import all address data).

I think the way to go about this is to process both people and address records, get the identities of each record when they're inserted, then add their identities to a join table as I go along.

I'm sure SSIS can handle this, I'm just having no luck finding the right way to even research this problem.

Comment: for each of record, it contains both `people`, `residential` and `mailing`?

Comment: Unclear.   What does the incoming data look like and what does your desired result look like?   Are Identity columns involved in any of the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize:

One row of data contains both person and address information. You know there is a relationship between Jason and 100 main because it's on the same row in the file. When it's loaded to tables, there's no way to "know" a relationship exists.

How can I solve this with SSIS:
A lot of this is going to come down to the needs of your system.

Three table method: StagedData, Person, Address

StagedData is going to look like a tabular representation of your source file with a surrogate key (identity/sequence object) associated to it. This gives us something unique to be able to reference.  `Data Flow Task: Flat File Source -> maybe Derived Column transformations to do any data polishing -> OLE DB/ADO.NET Destination`

In my Person and Address table, maybe I'd have a field referencing this key (SourceKey). `Execute SQL Task` (code approximately)

```
CREATE TABLE #TieBack (SourceKey int, PersonSurrogateKey int);

INSERT INTO
    dbo.Person
OUTPUT
    Inserted.SurrogateKey
,   Inserted.PersonSurrogateKey
INTO
    #TieBack
SELECT
    SD.Name
,   SD.SurrogateKey 
FROM
    dbo.StagedData AS SD
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Person AS PI WHERE PI.SurrogateKey = SD.SurrogateKey);

-- Now that our temporary table is backfilled, use that to link a 
-- staged row to the the Person entity for the purpose of 
-- populating the Address table
INSERT INTO
    dbo.Address
SELECT
    SD.AddressLine1
,   TB.PersonSurrogateKey
FROM
    dbo.StagedData AS SD
    INNER JOIN
        #TieBack AS TB
        ON TB.SurrogateKey = SD.SurrogateKey
 WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Address AS A WHERE A.PersonSurrogateKey = TB.PersonSurrogateKey);
```

Or, maybe I have a junction table that will associate a Person and a SourceKey and maybe an Address and SourceKey. Or maybe I use a sequence object to generate an contactable entity which is just an id number but all the information about that contactable entity tombstone data, address data, etc all gets tagged with the same number. There are pros and cons to all these approaches but that's not what was asked but you might need to account for that.

You might also be interested in the [Incremental Load](https://andyleonard.blog/2011/09/stairway-to-ssis-step-3-adding-rows-in-incremental-loads/) pattern as part of the Stairway to Integration Services series.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, SSIS cannot handle this.  There is no built-in way for SQL Server to return Identity values back to SSIS as rows are inserted.  You could probably build it with a script transformation, but it will be tedious to write and performance won't be great.

The way I would handle this is to insert your incoming data as-is into a staging table and then run a stored procedure that populates your three destination tables.  It will populate the Person table and Address table first, so that Identity columns get populated, and then it will populate the "join" table referring back to the staging table to relate Persons to Addresses, and joining to the new tables to get their Identity column values.